# JQuery Count words recursively on several objects and choose the first word of those with more than one word

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use JQuery to Count words recursively on several objects and choose the first word of those with more than one word. 
Am getting a 1 everytime i try:

```
  $(".middlelinks > li > a").each(function(index, element) {
      var words = $(element).val().split(' ');
      if(words.length > 1)
      {
         var node = $(element).contents().filter(function () { return this.nodeType == 3 }).first(),
        text = node.text(),
        first = text.slice(0, text.indexOf(" "));

        if (!node.length)
            return;

        node[0].nodeValue = text.slice(first.length);
        node.before('<span class="titleMaroon">' + first + '</span><br/>');
      }
      else{ alert(words.length);}
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can return .val() on an anchor tag. If you change that to .text() instead I believe it will solve your problem.

```
var words = $(element).text().split(' ');
```

JSFiddle Example - http://jsfiddle.net/49N76/3/